# What direction does the angular velocity of an object lie on if linear velocity is in XY axis?

Tags: rotational-kinematics

So,I was watching the solution of a question of rotational motion. The object's rotational motion was in XY plane. And the direction of angular velocity of the object was given to be along Z-axis in the solution. Now, I cannot understand how the angular velocity can possibly be along that direction. I expected it to be either along clockwise or anticlockwise direction, but on the XY plane either way.

So, please tell me where I am going wrong here. Also,I am a total beginner at this subject, so please frame your answers bearing  thing in mind.

Comment: After reading the [wiki on this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_three_dimensions) do you still have more a specific question ? It's is not obvious why it should be this way because it's a convention. But it makes sense probably after reading this you'll have more more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a particle that moves instantaneously in a circle of radius R about an axis perpendicular to the plane of motion. If the origin is a point on the axis, then the time rate of change of the position vector is its linear velocity, whose magnitude is $$v = R \omega$$
The directions of the vectors $\vec \omega, \vec r$ and $\vec v$ are orthonormal, and the direction of $\vec \omega$ is defined (by convention) such that
its positive direction is normal to the plane and corresponds to the direction of advance of a right-hand screw when turned in the same sense as the rotation of the particle ([the right hand screw rule](http://www3.eng.cam.ac.uk/%7Ehemh1/gyroscopes/screwrule.html#:%7E:text=The%20axis%20is%20%27grasped%27%20in,positive%20direction%2C%20and%20vice%20versa.)). It can even be defined this way:

[image]

Simply put, a counter-clockwise rotation corresponds to $\vec \omega$ being along the positive z - axis, and a clockwise rotation corresponds to $\vec \omega$ being along the negative z - axis.

Also, by doing so we can formuate the vector form of the previous equation:
$$\vec v = \vec \omega \times \vec r$$
which satisfies both, the equation relating their magnitudes, and the direction of the vector $\vec \omega$.

Hope this helps

---

[Image source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rotv.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a convention. Any instantaneous rotation of a particle defines a plane, in the example X-Y. And each plane has one and only one normal direction associated.

If we define the angular velocity as a vector normal to the plane of rotation, the vector modulus encodes its magnitude, the vector direction encodes the plane of rotation, and where the arrow points encodes if the rotation is CW or CCW.